# Stack overflow extension on resource intensive program

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm having problems with a stack overflow extension on a 450 line program, I need help to optimize it.

The error mostly appears on the `void datacheck()` and it calls an endless loop - which its not since it can complete the conditions, its just the hardest thing to do.

Here is what it should do:
[Diagram1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8RvW.png)
[Diagram2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxM43.png)

I'm really new to coding and don't see any room for improvement.

If you have experience and can help me optimize it would mean the world to me. Thanks guys!

```
    int mincount;
        int maxcount;

        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;
        int f;
        int g;
        int h;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        int l;
        int m;
        int n;
        int o;
        int p;
        int q;
        int r;
        int s;
        int t;
        int u;
        int v;
        int w;
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;

        void MinMax()
        {
            mincount = Convert.ToInt32(Min_Count.Text);
            mincount = int.Parse(Min_Count.Text);

            maxcount = Convert.ToInt32(Max_Count.Text);
            maxcount = int.Parse(Max_Count.Text);

            int a = mincount;
            int b = mincount;
            int c = mincount;
            int d = mincount;
            int e = mincount;
            int f = mincount;
            int g = mincount;
            int h = mincount;
            int i = mincount;
        }

        void datacheck(){
            if (a == b)
            {
                a++; datacheck();
            }
            if (a == c)
            {
                a++; datacheck();
            }
            if (a == d)
            {
                a++; datacheck();
            }
            if (a == e)
            {
                a++; datacheck();
            }
            if (a == f)
            {
                a++; datacheck();
            }
            if (a == g)
            {
                a++; datacheck();
            }
            if (a == h)
            {
                a++; datacheck();
            }
            if (a == i)
            {
                a++; datacheck();
            }

            if (b == c)
            {
                b++; datacheck();
            }
            if (b == d)
            {
                b++; datacheck();
            }
            if (b == e)
            {
                b++; datacheck();
            }
            if (b == f)
            {
                b++; datacheck();
            }
            if (b == g)
            {
                b++; datacheck();
            }
            if (b == h)
            {
                b++; datacheck();
            }
            if (b == i)
            {
                b++; datacheck();
            }


            if (c == d)
            {
                c++; datacheck();
            }
            if (c == e)
            {
                c++; datacheck();
            }
            if (c == f)
            {
                c++; datacheck();
            }
            if (c == g)
            {
                c++; datacheck();
            }
            if (c == h)
            {
                c++; datacheck();
            }
            if (c == i)
            {
                c++; datacheck();
            }

            if (d == e)
            {
                d++; datacheck();
            }
            if (d == f)
            {
                d++; datacheck();
            }
            if (d == g)
            {
                d++; datacheck();
            }
            if (d == h)
            {
                d++; datacheck();
            }
            if (d == i)
            {
                d++; datacheck();
            }

            if (e == f)
            {
                e++; datacheck();
            }
            if (e == g)
            {
                e++; datacheck();
            }
            if (e == h)
            {
                e++; datacheck();
            }
            if (e == i)
            {
                e++; datacheck();
            }


            if (f == g)
            {
                f++; datacheck();
            }
            if (f == h)
            {
                f++; datacheck();
            }
            if (f == i)
            {
                f++; datacheck();
            }

            if (g == h)
            {
                g++; datacheck();
            }
            if (g == i)
            {
                g++; datacheck();
            }

            if (h == i)
            {
                h++; datacheck();
            }

            newdata();
        }

        void newdata()
        {
            j = a * a;
            k = b * b;
            l = c * c;
            m = d * d;
            n = e * e;
            o = f * f;
            p = g * g;
            q = h * h;
            r = i * i;

            totals();
        }
        void totals() {
            s = j + k + l;

            t = m + n + o;

            u = p + q + r;

            v = j + m + p;

            w = k + n + q;

            x = l + o + r;

            y = j + n + r;

            z = p + n + l;

            check();
        }

        void check()
        {
            if (j != k)
            {
                plusone();
            }
            else
            {
                if (k != l)
                {
                    plusone();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (l != m)
                    {
                        plusone();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (m != n)
                        {
                            plusone();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (n != o)
                            {
                                plusone();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (o != p)
                                {
                                    plusone();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (p != q)
                                    {
                                        plusone();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (q != r)
                                        {
                                            plusone();
                                        }
                                        else { Eureka.Checked = true; }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

void plusone()
        {
            if (a < maxcount)
            {
                a++; checkb();
                string sa = a.ToString();
                valA.Text = (sa);

            }
            else { a = mincount; b++; checkb(); }
        }

        void checkb()
        {
            if (b < maxcount)
            {
                string sb = b.ToString();
                valC.Text = (sb); checkc();
            }
            else
            {
                b = mincount; c++; checkc();
            }

        }

        void checkc()
        {
            if (c < maxcount)
            {
                string sc = c.ToString();
                valC.Text = (sc); checkd();
            }
            else
            {
                c = mincount; d++; checkd();
            }
        }

        void checkd()
        {
            if (d < maxcount)
            {
                string sd = d.ToString();
                valC.Text = (sd); checke();
            }
            else
            {
                d = mincount; e++; checke();
            }
        }

        void checke()
        {
            if (e < maxcount)
            {
                string se = e.ToString();
                valC.Text = (se); checkf();
            }
            else
            {
                e = mincount; f++; checkf();
            }
        }

        void checkf()
        {
            if (f < maxcount) {
                string sf = f.ToString();
                valC.Text = (sf); checkg();
            }
            else { f = mincount; g++; checkg(); }
        }

        void checkg()
        {
            if (g < maxcount)
            {
                string sg = g.ToString();
                valC.Text = (sg); checkh();
            }
            else
            {
                g = mincount; h++; checkh();
            }
        }

        void checkh()
        {
            if (h < maxcount)
            {
                string sh = h.ToString();
                valC.Text = (sh); checki();
            }
            else
            {
                h = mincount; i++; checki();
            }
        }

        void checki()
        {
            if (i < maxcount) {
                string si = i.ToString();
                valC.Text = (si); datacheck();
            }
            else { NotHere.Checked = true; NotHere.Text = "FUCK"; }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            datacheck();
            Start.Text = "Restart";
        }
```

That was a long read

Comment: have you used arrays yet?

Comment: Follow your code. The first time, `a == b`, so `a++` (now a = 2) and then `datacheck` again. Then the next check passes: `a == c`. So now `b++` (now a and b = 2) and `datacheck`. Again, `a == b`. This will happen until your values overflow; but before that; you'll get your stack overflow exception. It's *incredibly* hard to figure out what the program should do - but this is *why* it's failing.

Comment: I have no idea what this application is supposed to do, and I'm certain it can be done much simpler :)

Comment: I added diagrams to explain what it should do

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learnt, break it all into different functions instead of reseting the same one over and over

```
void datachecka() {
        if (a == b)
        {
            a++;
        }
        if (a == c)
        {
            a++;
        }
        if (a == d)
        {
            a++;
        }
        if (a == e)
        {
            a++;
        }
        if (a == f)
        {
            a++;
        }
        if (a == g)
        {
            a++;
        }
        if (a == h)
        {
            a++;
        }
        if (a == i)
        {
            a++; visuala();
        }
    }
        void datacheckb() {
            if (b == c)
            {
                b++;
            }
            if (b == d)
            {
                b++;
            }
            if (b == e)
            {
                b++;
            }
            if (b == f)
            {
                b++;
            }
            if (b == g)
            {
                b++;
            }
            if (b == h)
            {
                b++;
            }
            if (b == i)
            {
                b++; visualb();
        }
        }
    void datacheckc() {
        if (c == d)
        {
            c++;
        }
        if (c == e)
        {
            c++;
        }
        if (c == f)
        {
            c++;
        }
        if (c == g)
        {
            c++;
        }
        if (c == h)
        {
            c++;
        }
        if (c == i)
        {
            c++; visualc();
        }
    }

    void datacheckd() {
        if (d == e)
        {
            d++;
        }
        if (d == f)
        {
            d++;
        }
        if (d == g)
        {
            d++;
        }
        if (d == h)
        {
            d++;
        }
        if (d == i)
        {
            d++; visuald();
        }
    }

    void datachecke() {
        if (e == f)
        {
            e++;
        }
        if (e == g)
        {
            e++;
        }
        if (e == h)
        {
            e++;
        }
        if (e == i)
        {
            e++; visuale();
        }
    }

    void datacheckf()
    {
        if (f == g)
        {
            f++;
        }
        if (f == h)
        {
            f++;
        }
        if (f == i)
        {
            f++; visualf();
        }
    }

    void datacheckg() {
        if (g == h)
        {
            g++;
        }
        if (g == i)
        {
            g++; visualg();
        }
    }

    void datacheckh() { 
        if (h == i)
        {
            h++; visualh();
        }
       }
```

thats how datacheck() ended up like

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the or (||) operator.

```
void datacheckf()
{
    if (f == g || f == h || f == i) {
        f++;
    }
    if (f == i) {
        visualf();
    }
}
```